# Compute $\lim\limits _{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{\ln (\ln n)}\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k\ln k}$ without Taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Evaluate
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k\ln k}}{\ln (\ln n)}$$

without Taylor series.

I applied Stolz–Cesàro's theorem:

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k\ln k}}{\ln (\ln n)} = 
\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k\ln k} - \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k\ln k}}{\ln (\ln (n+1)) - \ln (\ln n)} =  
\lim _{n\to \infty } \frac{\frac{1}{(n+1) \ln(n+1)}}{\ln (\ln (n+1)) - \ln (\ln n)}$$

I don't know how to continue this. The answer should be $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)\cdot\ln\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)\cdot\ln\big[(1+\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln n}{\ln n})^{\frac{\ln n}{\ln(n+1)-\ln n}}\big]^{\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln n}{\ln }}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}\cdot(\ln(n+1)-\ln n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\ln{(\frac{n+1}{n}})^{n+1}\cdot\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\ln[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n]^{\frac{n+1}{n}}\cdot\frac{\ln n+\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\ln n}} = 1$$
This makes use of the well-known $$\lim_{f(x)\to 0}(1+f(x))^{\frac{1}{f(x)}} = e$$

Answer (score 4):

Because $\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}$ is decreasing,$$\int_{2}^{n}\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx\leq \sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k\ln(k)}\leq\frac{1}{2\ln(2)}+\int_{2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx$$
The left hand side is equal to $$\int_{2}^{n}\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx=\ln\ln(n)-\ln\ln(2)$$
while the right hand side is $$\frac{1}{2\ln(2)}+\int_{2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx = \frac{1}{2\ln(2)}+\ln\ln(n-1)-\ln\ln(2)$$
Both of these divided by $\ln\ln n$ approaches $1$, so by the Squeeze theorem the original term approaches $1$ as well.